# По какой причине в списке res значения элементов line меняется, нужно просто все значения line сделать подсписком res

Tags: python, list

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c']
line, res = [], []
n = len(s)
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(n):
        line += s[j]
        if len(line) == i:
            print(line)
            res.append(line)
            line.pop(0)
    line = []
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['a']
['b']
['c']
['a', 'b']
['b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
[[], [], [], ['c'], ['c'], ['b', 'c']]
```

https://stepik.org/lesson/416753/step/14?auth=login&unit=406261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line` является изменяемым объектом (списком), и когда вы добавляете его в `res.append(line)`, в `res` добавляется ссылка на изменяемый объект `line`, поэтому, когда вы делаете `line.pop(0)`, из line удаляется первый элемент, и точно так же он удаляется из того `line`, который вы добавили в `res`, потому что это один и  тот же `line`. Самый простой способ - вставлять скопированное значение `line`, вместо исходного, например так:

```py
s = ['a', 'b', 'c']
line, res = [], []
n = len(s)
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(n):
        line += s[j]
        if len(line) == i:
            print(line)
            res.append(line[:])
            line.pop(0)
    line = []
print(res)
```

Итоговый `res` будет выглядеть так:

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

(обратите внимание на добавленную конструкцию `[:]`). Она создает копию списка `line`, от первого до последнего элемента. Если такой способ вам не понятен, почитайте про срезы в питоне, или используйте на 9й строке такой способ:
`res.append(line.copy())` или `res.append(list(line))`